# Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler in Spring

Tags: java, spring, uncaughtexceptionhandler

I am developing a Spring application, and was wondering if there's a part of the framework that lets me do something like this in a more elegant way, such as configuring something in XML?

Comment: In what context?  What actual problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Sorry I should have elaborated.  In this case I am writing an uncaught exception handler which writes the stack trace to my log4j file.  While straightforward to implement I was wondering if there was a "Spring way" of doing things.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the purpose of your question is to set a custom `UncaughtExceptionHandler` through your application context, you can use:

```xml
<bean id="myhandler" class="java.lang.ThreadGroup">
    <constructor-arg value="Test"/>
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
   <property name="targetClass" value="java.lang.Thread"/>
   <property name="targetMethod" value="setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler"/>
   <property name="arguments">
     <list>
         <ref bean="myhandler" />
     </list>
   </property>
</bean>
```

(N.B. replace myhandler with an `Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler` of choice...)

Comment: This is the "more elegant way"? How is this better than doing it in Java?

Comment: Without context I've not really got an opinion on whether it is elegant or not, but I can see the reasoning of doing this versus creating a separate Java class just to set the uncaught exception handler on startup.

Comment: I do think this is more elegant, as setting the handler is part of your applications configuration which spring is supposed to be in control off.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `@ControllerAdvice` annotated classes for uncaught exception handling. Referencing from https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc, the following code will catch any Exception:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class MyUncaughtExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(value = Exception.class)
    public void defaultExceptionHandler(Exception e) {
        // do whatever you want with the exception
    } 
}
```

Comment: IT will catch any Exception thrown by a Controller